# Add item to already existing array - MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have the following route in my Node JS backend that utilizes the $push operator to add a userId to an already existing array called "followers":

```
const followUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  const { follower } = req.body

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).json({error: 'No such user'})
  }

  const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {
    $push: {
      "followers" : follower
    }
  })

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({error: 'No such user'})
  }

  res.status(200).json(user)
}
```

In the react frontend, I use to following async function to add the user to the array:

```
const handleFollow = async (e) => {

  const response = await fetch(`/api/user/follow/${params.userId}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(user.id),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${user.token}`
    }
  })
}
```

When I click a button that calls the function, the POST request submits successfully, but nothing changes in the database. All help appreciated!

Comment: If `body` is a stringified user id, `body.follower` is bound to be undefined, so nothing to push. Change that to: `const follower = req.body`

Comment: In this line `const { follower } = req.body` you are trying to **extract** a value named "follower" from the `req.body` object. Since `req.body` only contains `JSON.stringify(user.id)`, follower is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for your help - that worked! Another part of the issue was that I did not set `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.